# How to separate records from database column and compare then in query ignoring the second text in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table in oracle

```
review (
   review_id      pk,
   review_name    varchar2,
   review_viewers varchar2
)
```

The `review_viewers` column contains the combination of user's `user_name` and `last_name` and it will contain multiple record separated by colon(`:`).

for example :

```
(1,'Planning','John Smith:Max Payne:Maria Garcia');
```

Now I want to write a query which will convert the above `review_viewers` into individual user like 'John Smith','Max Payne' striping ":" from it and then only use the `user_name` from that string to compare.

For Example i only want to compare values

> 'John','Max' and 'Maria'

as they are unique.

My query will be like following :

```
SELECT 1 FROM REVIEW WHERE review_viewers = [Input from user]
```

> The Input from user will always be a single string for example 'Max' or 'John' etc.

How can i accomplish it? I tried it several time but I am always hitting a dead end.

Comment: Don't store multiple values as delimited strings. Fix your database design and the query becomes simple

Answer (score 1):

```
variable userinput varchar2(20);
execute :userinput := 'Max';    


select review_id, review_name, review_reviewers, 
    regexp_substr(review_reviewers, '(^|:)(' || :userinput || '\s.+?)(:|$)', 1, 1, null, 2) 
    from review 
    where regexp_like(review_reviewers, '(^|:)' || :userinput || '\s');
```